# Conversion from string "update bk_details set totalcopie" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

where is wrong. I got error at line second. error is **"Conversion from string "update bk_details set totalcopie" to type 'Double' is not valid."**

```
   Dim totalbook As Integer
   totalbook = totalbook - 1
myConnection.Open()
                myCommand = New SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand("update bk_details set totalcopies = '" + totalbook + "' where bid like '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", myConnection)
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes after `totalcopies` and try.

Comment: @ shree.pat18 : - yes i do this but still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Always use  '&' for string concatanation not +!

Also you should be using paramatised queries for SQL to make it safer!

Hope this helped,
Rodi